# How to set a var in struts2 from Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, struts2

```
 fngetThings(thingId)//getting thingId from the included jsp page
    {
    var test1 = thingId;//I need to set this test1 value to a  in the same asp page
    $("#test2").val(test1);
    }
```

In the same Jsp Page      .

```
    If i use the below tags it is working fine 
    <s:textfield name="test2" id = "test2"></s:textfield>
    or
    <s:hidden name="test2" id = "test2"></s:hidden>
```

I am unable to set test1 value in a variable like 
        `<s:set var="testVar2" value="" id="test2"/>` 
I need to use that test1 value for some test conditions.

I tried writing `$("#test2").attr("value",test1)` in the function this is also not working.

Can someone please help me with this

```
<s:set var="testVar2" value="" id="test2"/> //how to set value=test1 from script.
```

Comment: Your code seems unformatted.

Comment: yes, you are unable to set it, why do you need so, the variable might already set by you or changed thereafter.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. You obviously cannot set an S2 value from JS. You *can* set an S2 value using `<s:set>`, if you're saying it's not working, then you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Roman C: I need to use that value to perform some test operations. So I am trying to set <s:set/> tag from Jquery.

Comment: @shruthi Unable isn't said possible, it's unclear what value and which variable do you want to set. Clarify your question to precisely point to the problem you have. Also remove any unrelated code that only messing up your question.

Comment: `asp page` ? Alter `<s:set/>` with javascript ? `var` and `id` at the same time ? Only 2 close-votes ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

`<s:set var="testVar2"  id="test2"/>`

then to print
`<s:property value="testVar2"/>`